# Getting error while i am creating chart in axelor?

Tags: xml, bar-chart

Here is my chart.xml file

> http://axelor.com/xml/ns/object-views/object-views_5.2.xsd">
>
> ```
> <chart name="chart.sales.per.month" title="Sales per month">
>
>     <dataset type="jpql">
>         <![CDATA[   SELECT
>   SUM(totalAmount) AS amount,
>   EXTRACT(MONTH FROM orderDate) AS month
> ```
>
> FROM
>         Order
>
> WHERE
>         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM orderDate) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM orderDate)
>
> GROUP BY
>
> ```
>   EXTRACT(MONTH FROM orderDate)   ORDER BY
>   month   ]]>
>     </dataset>
>     <category key="month" type="month"/>
>     <series key="amount"  type="bar"/>
> </chart> </object-views>
> ```

I am getting this
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /axelor-erp-5.1.12/partials/views/chart.html

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.30

please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Need more details on how you run the axelor erp. Are you using official war package or built by yourself? Also, try tomcat8.5 instead of tomcat9 and use JDK8 only.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution actually I am executing directly chart.xml file instead of in dashboard file with the help of dashlet command.